# Некорректно работает html_entity_decode

Tags: php

На сайте cms opencart Версия ocStore 2.1.0.1
На странице блога выводится кратное описание записи и кнопка "Читать дальше".
Код шаблона:

```
        <div class="blog-desc">
            <?php $topic['description'] = html_entity_decode($topic['description']);
            echo $topic['description']; ?></div>
        <div class="read-more-button"><a href="<?php echo urldecode(urldecode($topic['href'])); ?>">Читать дальше</a></div>
```

запись в админке:

```html
<p style="font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;; font-size: 13px;">текст</p>

<p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;; font-size: 13px;">текст</p>
```

код, сохраняющий запись в бд:

```
$desc=utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $setting['char_limit']) . '...';
```

в результате html-код ломается, и разметка выглядит примерно так:

```html
<p style="font-family: sans-serif,… </div>
   <div class=" read-more-button"=""><a href="#">Читать дальше</a></p>
```

Если в php сделать так:

```
$topic['description'] = 
    html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode($topic['description']));
```

то вёрстка также ломается
Кстати в некоторых записях вёрстка не ломается.
Подскажите, как можно это исправить.

**P.S.**

```
 <?php foreach ($blogs as $blog) { ?>
     <?php foreach ($blog['blog_data'] as $topic) { ?>
```

кстати в админке подключён модуль Megnor Blog > LatestBlog.
может быть он как-то по своему сохраняет?

**P.S.** обновил ещё вопрос, код контроллера

```
            foreach ($module_blogs as $module_blog) {

                $total_comments = $this->model_megnor_blogger->getTotalBlogComments($module_blog['blogger_id']);

                $description = strip_tags($module_blog['description']);
                $description = iconv_substr($description, 0, 500);
                $description = rtrim($description, "!,.-");
                $description = substr($description, 0, strrpos($description, ' '));
                $description .= "… ";


                $module_blog_data[] = array(
                    'title' => $module_blog['title'],
                    'image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($module_blog['image'], $setting['width'], $setting['height']),
                    'description' => $description,
                    'date_added' => date('d/n/y', strtotime($module_blog['date_added'])),
                    'total_comments' => number_format($total_comments),
                    'href' => $this->url->link('information/blogger', 'blogger_id=' . $module_blog['blogger_id'], 'SSL')
                );

            }

            $data['blogs'][] = array(
                'name' => $module['name'],
                'blog_data' => $module_blog_data
            );
```

код модели:

```
public function getTotalBlogComments($blogger_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "blogger_comment WHERE blogger_id = '" . (int)$blogger_id . "'");

    if ($query->row) {
        return $query->row['total'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function getBlogsByModule($module_id, $limit = 0) {
    if ($limit) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "blogger b LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blogger_description bd ON (b.blogger_id = bd.blogger_id) WHERE b.status = '1' AND bd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND b.module_id = '" . (int)$module_id . "' ORDER BY b.date_added DESC LIMIT " . (int)$limit);
    } else {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "blogger b LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blogger_description bd ON (b.blogger_id = bd.blogger_id) WHERE b.status = '1' AND bd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND b.module_id = '" . (int)$module_id . "' ORDER BY b.date_added DESC");
    }

    return $query->rows;
}
```

Comment: покажите, от куда берётся переменная $topic

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin, обновил вопрос

Comment: $description = substr($description, 0, strrpos($description, ' ')); уберите эту строчку, что получается?

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin ничего не поменялось, без изменений

Comment: если в контроллере удалить переменную description, кроме этой `$description = strip_tags($module_blog['description']);`, то выводится вся запись, кнопка "читать далее" в конце всей записи, но вёрстка не ломается.

Comment: благодарю, что навели на мысль. 
нужно было добавить кодировку `$description = iconv_substr($description, 0, 500, "UTF-8");`

Comment: теперь нормально

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin нет, ещё не нормально, в футере теперь ломается вёрстка, блок container не закрывается перед футером

Comment: если убрать конкретно эту запись, то ничего не ломается. Подскажите, что ещё нужно исправить?